# My understanding of threading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have not programmed in over a year now so sorry if this is a stupid question.
I looked up lots of examples on this site for threading but I seem to be getting a different outcome to other people.

From my understanding of threading, using this simple code, it should be printing YO and LO together, something like

YO
LO
YO
LO

but instead I just get

YO 
YO 
YO
...

```
from threading import Thread

import time

def printYo():
        while(3>1):
            print ("YO")
            time.sleep(1)

def printLo():
        while(3>1):
            print ("LO")
            time.sleep(1)

t2 = Thread(target=printLo())
t = Thread(target=printYo())
t2.start()
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function instead of just giving it as target for your thread.

```
t2 = Thread(target=printLo)
t = Thread(target=printYo)
```

Comment: Ah...embarrassing. Using python 3 alone has been causing me error messages, screwing things myself is not helping.

Comment: I have, but I had to wait a few minutes before It would allow me. Which is an odd system.

Comment: @user1817988 It's not odd at all when you think about it. Calling a function means to call it immediately, the `Thread` object would not get any information about what function that contains the thread code (unless the called function happens to return a callable object).

Comment: No no no, I mean it is odd the website doesn't let me accept the thread as answered until 3+ mins after I get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, first of all you should pass the thread function to the `Thread` constructor (ie `Thread(target=printLo)`). When the thread is started it will call that function in a separate thread.

Second you may (probably) want to keep the main thread running which could be done by having an idle loop. If you don't you will not be able to stop it with ^C, but you still has to handle the termination of the process.

The complete code will consequently be:

```
from threading import Thread

import time

def printYo():
        while(3>1):
            print ("YO")
        time.sleep(1)

def printLo():
        while(3>1):
            print ("LO")
            time.sleep(1)

t2 = Thread(target=printLo)
t = Thread(target=printYo)

t2.start()
t.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    os._exit(0)
```

A minor note is that the prints will print the output on separate lines, an important note is that there is no guarantee which order the YOs and LOs will be printed - at first they are likely to alternate, but eventually some of the threads may get to print twice before the other gets to print.

Comment: No, if your main thread stop, your program still continue to run, awaiting the other threads are finishing their job (and you can't interupt it, you must kill it). Maybe what you are talking about is only viable on Windows, but I'm sure under Linux

Comment: @FunkySayu Thank's for pointing that out. I think it's a good idea to keep the main thread for the reason you pointed out. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: In fact, even if you interupt the main Thread, your sub threads will continue to run. In order to avoid that, you must create some stop conditions like defining a boolean `is_alive` and modifying the `while (3>1)` to `while (3>1 and is_alive)`. Next, you must handle the KeyboardInterupt and set `is_alive` to `False`. But that's not the point of this question.

Comment: @FunkySayu I forgot that python throws exception on ^C, that has to be caught and real `exit` has to be called in order to get the behavior I intended. I've updated it again.